# Laravel query build based on relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, relation

I have such query:

```
Tournament::has('participations', '<', '2')->get();
```

How can I replace constant number '2' on tournament's column named slots ?? I would like retrieve only these tournaments which have least participants than slots in tournament.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by using the column name instead of "2". Like you would do in "normal" SQL

```
Tournament::has('participations', '<', 'slots')->get();
```

Now, you don't even have to try that because it won't work. But why's that? Because Laravel treats `slots` like a string and escapes it so SQL does as well.

What you need to do, is use `DB::raw()`. `raw` makes sure Laravel changes nothing and just injects it into the SQL query

```
Tournament::has('participations', '<', DB::raw('slots'))->get();
```

#### Update

After some trying out I found this: (Its not very pretty but the only way I got it working)

```
$subquery = function($q) use ($uid){
    $q->where('player_id', $uid);
}

Tournament::whereHas('participations', $subquery)
    ->whereHas('participations', $subquery, '<', DB::raw('slots'))
    ->get();
```

The first `whereAs` checks for `count(*) > 0`, the second `count(*) < slots` and the subquery filters by player id.

Comment: thank you, it works. Do you know how to expand this query by smth like this:

    (select count(*) > 0 from participations where tournament_id= tournament.id and player_id = '.$uid.') as isParticipating

where $uid is current logged user id. I just want to retrieve if logged user participates in this tournament or not.

Comment: @Lukas I updated my answer, hope this is what you needed